# Time quanta for Mixpanel custom alerts

Tags: mixpanel

When creating custom alerts, how is the time quanta used for the alerts determined? e.g. events per minute vs per hour vs per 24hrs etc..

Could not find anything that addresses this in the Mixpanel docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur here from Mixpanel. I've spoken with our product team to clarify our [docs](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028142571-Custom-Alerts), and we'll be making updates to them soon.

To answer your question - the time quanta for our Insights report, 'Line' graph setting, depends on the time unit you've selected in the saved Insights report as indicated by the blue annotation box in this screenshot, i.e.

- Minute
- Hour
- Day
- Week
- Month
- Quarter

[image]

Once selected, you will then have the option to be alerted based on a 'relative' or 'absolute' threshold option, and we will alert you at most once an hour, day or week.

'Absolute' - if and when the past minute, hour, day, week, month or quarter exceeds the value you've specified, we will alert you.

'Relative' - if and when the past minute, hour, day, week, month or quarter is higher or lower than that of the previous time-period, we will alert you.

Let me know if you have any follow-up questions!

Comment: That makes the quanta clear when creating an alert, but how can I determine the quanta for an existing alert? thanks

Comment: NVM, looks like the alert is always tied to a report, so if you change the report, then you inherently change the alert?